# Can't Catch ArgumentException

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, graphics, drawing, picturebox

I am building a game in vb.net.

I need to update my screen (PictureBox), From several threads.

My Update Function :

```
  Private Delegate Sub NonInput()
  Public Sub UpdateMyScreen()
      If BarScreen.InvokeRequired() Then
          BarScreen.Invoke(New NonInput(AddressOf UpdateMyScreen))
      Else
          Try
              BarScreen.Refresh()
          Catch ex As System.ArgumentException  
             'Some Code
          End Try
      End If
  End Sub
```

Now my game starts fine and runs good, but when I resize the BarScreen control (on run time) it throws me an ArgumentException Exception.

Now this is not my problem,

My problem is why the Try and Catch are not catching the Exception ?, Am I doing something wrong ?

Photo of the Exception :

[image]

Comment: Try to manage this exception inside the global asax

Comment: Regardless of the error. Debug the Paint event, find and fix the error that lives there.

Comment: There are no Paint event, When I refresh a picturebox it  draws to screen the image of the picturebox. I mean that if I change the image of the picturebox  I will not see it until I refresh the control.

Comment: What? show some more code then.

Comment: @OneFineDay what do you mean by showing more code, I have 4000 lines of code !

Comment: come think about it-what code as anything to do with this?

Comment: If you change an image in a picturebox you don't have to call refresh. It has always updated as soon as I assigned a new image.

Comment: Well I an not changeing the image I am drawing on it (I draw dirctly on the image), so to see the update I need to refresh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72435/discussion-between-green-fire-and-onefineday).